# Wordpress Admin Menu turn off https

Tags: wordpress

I'm running wordpress 3.3.2 on IIS 6.

The admin menu function to logout is https when I don't have https.

How can I turn off https?  I've played with the source with no luck

Thanks

Comment: Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I'd try not to play with the source as much as you can.  This is referred to as "hacking the core" and it's a widely frowned upon practice.  All code you change in the core will be lost from subsequent updates and also might not work with other plugins, widgets, or themes you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

I deinstalled a facebook plugin for wordpress and it fixed the issue.